# Why does the form submit event fire when I have stopped propagation at the submit button level?

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, events, jquery-events

**HTML**

```
<form>
    <input type='text'>
    <button type='submit'>Submit</button>
</form>
```

**JavaScript**

```
$('form').on('submit', function(e) {
    alert('submit');
    e.preventDefault();
});

$('button').on('click', function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    alert('clicked');
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dn9vwwxo/3/)

---

After watching the great video [here](http://www.kirupa.com/html5/event_capturing_bubbling_javascript.htm), I understand that when I click the submit button, the event bubbles up to the form, and the form's submit event is then triggered. Which explains why "clicked" is alerted before "submit" (before I add `e.stopPropagation()` to the button handler).

But when I add `e.stopPropagation()` to the button handler, "submit" is still alerted. Why? I thought that `stopPropagation` prevents the event from bubbling up to the `form`, and so the `form.on('submit')` listener shouldn't be "hearing" an event.

Comment: You're stopping the click from propogating up the chain, you're not stopping the submit event

Comment: @adeneo So how does the submit event get triggered?

Comment: It get's triggered because the default behaviour of a submit button is to submit the form, but stopping propagation only stops the current event from moving up to parent elements, in this case `click`

Comment: e.stoppropogation: http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/event_stoppropagation.asp

Answer (score 14, accepted):

When you click a submit button in a form the click event spawns on the button and bubbles up. The submit event spawns on the form (not the button) and bubbles up from there.

If you stop propagation on the click event you're just stopping the bubbling phase of the click event. This has no effect on the submit event.

To stop the submit action you have to add a check to the submit handler.

Keep in mind that adding `e.preventDefault()` on the click handler in the button is not enough to prevent the submit event from spawning since there are more ways to submit a form than just clicking a button. (pressing <kbd>enter</kbd> in an input field for instance).

Comment: I guess what I'm not understanding is how the submit event "starts off". The way I was imagining it is coming from the click event on the submit button, but I guess that's not how it works. Could you elaborate on how the submit event "starts off"?

Comment: This _default_ behavior is programmed into the engine. The behaviors are standardized across browsers. If you press enter in an input field that is in a form a submit will be generated on the form. Similarly if you click a submit button that is in a form it will generate a submit event on the form. There are many more of these behaviors. You can prevent them with `.preventDefault()`. You can probably see why it's unwise to try and capture all possible events that might also generate a submit event. It's much easier to just deal with the submit event if it happens.

Comment: Please note, in IE, if you `preventDefault` the event for pressing "Enter" on a dropdown, it will break the default behaviour for selecting an item (spacebar to open dropdown, "Enter" to select).

Comment: I wonder what would happen if there is a nested form!, inner submit will propagate to the outer form's onsubmit. Hm interesting

Comment: @Biboswan you can't nest `<form>` tags, similarly you can't nest `<a>` tags.

Answer (score 6):

See the handler

```
$('button').on('click', function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
```

Note that the event is `click`, so you're stopping the `click` event from propagating up the chain, and that doesn't interact with the `submit` event at all, that still fires as the default action of a submit button is to submit the form, and the way to stop that is to prevent that default action with `preventDefault`

In other words, `stopPropagation` only stops the current event being handled from propagating to parent elements, it does not stop the default behaviour of the element, that would be `preventDefault` !

Answer (score 2):

You need `e.preventDefault();` in the button click as well:

```js
$('form').on('submit', function(e) {
    alert('submit');
    e.preventDefault();
});

$('button').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    alert('clicked');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
    <input type='text'/>
    <button type='submit'>Submit</button>
</form>
```

Comment: True that @DontVoteMeDown. Actually the `stopPropagation` isn't needed here. The `button` element in the context of a `form` submits the form by default. So we are stopping it from performing it's default functionality.